# How can I write the on Laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[The is my DB table screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tquu8.png)

```php
$query = DB::table('categories');
$query->select('categorsies.*', 'c2.value as name', 'c2.store_id as store_id', 'c2.attribute_id as attribute_id', 'c2.entity_id as entity_id');

if ($this->store_id != 0) {
    $query->where('c2.store_id', $this->store_id)->orWhere('store_id', 0);
} else {
    $query->where('c2.store_id', $this->store_id);
}

$result_data = $query->get();
```

I want to get the row, if there is a store_id match get that row from the table otherwise get 0 default row

Comment: I didn't understand...
Can you format your code and explain what's wrong with what you wrote / what you expected

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `c2` table in your query. Also, you could use `when` to get the if statement logic in the query.

```php
$query = DB::table('categories')
    ->when(
        $this->store_id != 0,
        fn ($query) => $query->where('store_id', $this->store_id)->orWhere('store_id', 0),
        fn ($query) => $query->where('store_id', $this->store_id)
    )
    ->get();
```